# How to write factorygirl for table that have fields containing ruby keyword?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have a table with one of the field named `end`. How do I write the factory for that table:

I try to use quote but it's not working:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :open_hour do
    location
    day { Date::DAYNAMES.sample.downcase }
    start { Time.now.strftime('%H:%M') }
    'end' { Time.now.strftime('%H:%M') }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From [FactoryGirl docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/4.3.0/FactoryGirl/DefinitionProxy#method_missing_details):

> ```
> factory :user do
>   name 'Billy Idol'
> end
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> factory :user do
>   add_attribute :name, 'Billy Idol'
> end
> ```
>
> are equivalent.

Comment: in this case `add_attribute :end, Time.now.strftime('%H:%M')` ?

Comment: No, that's equivalent to (the hypothetical) `end Time.now....`, which will have a specific (always same) value as default. You want `add_attribute :end { Time.now.... }` if you want to keep the same functionality (i.e. a newly fetched value for each default).

Comment: This format works with a field with space: `add_attribute 'Start Time', 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use canonical ruby way, because 'end' is a function is this case, you can call it as `object.send :method, [args]`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :open_hour do
    location
    day { Date::DAYNAMES.sample.downcase }
    start { Time.now.strftime('%H:%M') }
    send :end, Time.now.strftime('%H:%M')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Having had some awful issues in the past when trying to do this, I'd advise that you rename those fields to 'start_time' and 'end_time'. There may be other unanticipated issues caused by having fields/methods named 'end', and tracking them down can be extremely annoying. 'end_time' also has the virtue of more clearly explaining what it is.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll rename both start and end into `start_time` and `end_time`.